# Eloquent ORM One to many query is not working

Tags: eloquent, laravel-5.4

I am working with laravel 5.4. I have created countries and states table.

countries table looks like below

[image]

And my states table is :

[image]

Here, I have written join query as shown in below. It works perfect.

```
$state = DB::table($this->tbl_states)
                ->join($this->tbl_countries, $this->tbl_countries.'.id', '=', $this->tbl_states.'.country_id')
                ->select($this->tbl_states.'.*', $this->tbl_countries.'.name as country_name')
                ->whereNull($this->tbl_states.'.deleted_at')
                ->paginate(10)
```

But, Instead of writing this query I want to use Eloquent ORM so what query should I have to write?

In Country model I have create function that looks like below :

```
public function states()
{
    return $this->hasMany('state');
}
```

And in State model I have write function that looks like below :

```
public function country()
{
    return $this->hasOne('country');
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `Country` model try this:

```
public function states()
{
    return $this->hasMany(App\State::class);
}
```

And in `State` model:

```
public function country()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(App\Country::class);
}
```

And then `$country->states` will give you all states of this country. As well as `$state->country` will return state's country.

Official Docs: [Eloquent: Relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#defining-relationships)